# Getting char from string at specified index

Tags: vba, ms-word

As stated how to get char from string at specified index in VBA (Visual Basic for Applications)? I searched Google and these do not work:

`s(index)` ,
`s.Chars(index)`,`s,Characters(index)`

So how to get char at specified index?

Comment: `Dim character As Integer
s = ActiveDocument.Content.Text
character = Asc(s.Mid(2))` I get invalid qualifier.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

If `s` is your string than you could do it this way:

```
Mid(s, index, 1)
```

**Edit** based on comment below question.

It seems that you need a bit different approach which should be easier. Try in this way:

```
Dim character As String 'Integer if for numbers
's = ActiveDocument.Content.Text - we don't need it
character = ActiveDocument.Characters(index)
```

Answer (score 0):

Getting one char from string at specified index

```
Dim pos As Integer
Dim outStr As String
pos = 2 
Dim outStr As String
outStr = Left(Mid("abcdef", pos), 1)
```

outStr="b"

Comment: What is the point of the Left function when Mid has a length argument?

Answer (score 0):

```
char = split_string_to_char(text)(index)

------

Function split_string_to_char(text) As String()

   Dim chars() As String
   For char_count = 1 To Len(text)
      ReDim Preserve chars(char_count - 1)
      chars(char_count - 1) = Mid(text, char_count, 1)
   Next
   split_string_to_char = chars
End Function
```