# Validating the format of a userform textbox entry

Tags: validation, excel, textbox, userform, vba

I have a UserForm for a database data extractor I'm making. In it there is a TextBox for typing in the part number that the user wants to extract data for. I want to validate that the user has entered the correct format of part number before the bulk of the extractor runs. To do this I need a code to validate that the text is entered in the specific format:

3 Numeric Characters
1 Alphabetic Character or 1 Hyphon
then 5 Numeric Characters

I tried the following validations at first:

```
'validate that box is not empty 

If TextBox1.Value = "" Then 

MsgBox ("Sorry, you need to provide an Amount") 

TextBox1.SetFocus 

Exit Sub 

End If 


'validate that box is numeric 

If Not IsNumeric(TextBox1.Value) Then 

MsgBox ("Sorry, must enter a numer") 

TextBox1.SetFocus 

Exit Sub 

End If
```

But then I realised that I had the problem that there may be an alphabetic char or hyphon in the fourth position.

I would appreciate any suggestions.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Anyway take a look here to get char at certains positions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17127272/getting-char-from-string-at-specified-index-in-the-visual-basic And you can then test caracters, or you can extract substring and analyse them (`IsNumeric()` etc ...)

Comment: @smagnan
I already have the following:

'validate that box is not empty
 
If TextBox1.Value = "" Then 

MsgBox ("Sorry, you need to provide an Amount") 

TextBox1.SetFocus 

Exit Sub 

End If 


'validate that box is numeric 

If Not IsNumeric(TextBox1.Value) Then 

MsgBox ("Sorry, must enter a numer") 

TextBox1.SetFocus 

Exit Sub 

End If 


But then I realised that I would have to account for either an alphabetic or hyphon in the 4th position, so I needed to change the code, but I am new to this so was unsure how to do so, I will be able to do the get-char methods though, so thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A beginner way to check this input is to just chop up the input string and compare the parts as needed:

```
Const alpha as String = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz-"
Dim strValue as String
Dim msg as String
strValue = TextBox1.Value

'Make sure it's the right LENGTH
If Len(strValue) <> 9 Then 
    msg = "Please enter the ID as 3 numeric, 1 alpha/hyphen, 5 numeric"
    GoTo EarlyExit
End If

'Check the first three for numeric:
If Not IsNumeric(Left(strValue), 3) Then
    msg = "The first three characters should be numeric"
    GoTo EarlyExit
End If

'Check the middle character, assuming case not sensitive:
If Instr(1, alpha, Lcase(Mid(strValue, 4, 1)) = 0 Then 
    msg = "The fourth character should be hyphen or alphabet"
    GoTo EarlyExit
End If

'Check the last four characters
If Not IsNumeric(Right(strValue, 4)) Then
    msg = "The last four characters should be numeric"
    GoTo EarlyExit
End If

'If you've gotten here, then the input is validated:
Exit Sub 

EarlyExit:
MsgBox msg
TextBox1.SetFocus
End Sub
```

3 Numeric Characters 1 Alphabetic Character or 1 Hyphon then 5 Numeric Characters