# check a specific character in textbox visual basic?

Tags: vb.net, vba

Lets say i have a textbox containing the string "hello".

Is there a way in which can i check that the 3rd character of textbox.text = "l"?

We are talking about visual basic, of course.

Thanks!

Comment: Please read [Ask] and take the [Tour].  This shows no effort to solve the problem yourself.  Also VB.NET IsNot vba

Comment: [Searching within strings for the presence of substrings](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/vba/3480/searching-within-strings-for-the-presence-of-substrings#t=201611081817391650478), from the [Documentation] button right here on this page.

Comment: [**`String.Chars()` property**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.chars(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Consider the possibility that the string might be less than 3 characters.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting char from string at specified index in the visual basic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17127272/getting-char-from-string-at-specified-index-in-the-visual-basic)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use this function

```
Private Function checkCharacter(thisString As String,
                                searchCharacter As Char,
                                index As Integer)
    Try
        Return thisString(index) = searchCharacter
    Catch
        Return False
    End Try
End Function
```

Call it like this

```
Dim result As Boolean = checkCharacter(TextBox1.Text, "l"c, 2)
```