# How to change filename using macro?

Tags: vba, ms-word

Now I have a document and i want to save it but the filename should be iterative 
eg. 1.docx then if i run the macro it should save as 2.docx and so on.
can I take a word from the document as the variable for the filename
eg. I want to use the 45th word in my document as the filename 
So how can i do it?

Comment: Show us what you have tried... https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

I don't have word open at the moment, so cannot code specific examples. What follows is hints on how to find your answer.

In word, you can select a range of text. Within these ranges are a number of built-in collections. "Paragraphs" and "Words" are some of the examples.
The easiest way to address your question is to select the Document Range, and then iterate through the Words collection until you get to the 45th word.

However, [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/word-vba/articles/range-words-property-word) notes that some non-words are also kept in this collection, so you may want to filter as you iterate. (*as an aside, be careful with their example, deleting items in a for-each loop has consequences*)

Assuming "rngWords" is your selected document range (words collection), you could would be similar to (not true code):

```
Counter = 0
selectedWord = ""
for iterator = 1 to rngWords.Count
    loopWord = rngWords(iterator)
    if trueword then Counter = Counter + 1
    if counter = 45 then  ' magic number = 45 based on your post.
        selectedword = loopWord
        exit loop
    end if
next iterator
```

You can experiment (e.g. `debug.print loopWord`) to work out how to determine a true word. You will also have to address what happens if you don't have 45 words in your document - e.g. you could take the last word. Probably the best way is to check the count first (`if rngWords.Count < 45 then .... else (loop)`)

Answer (score -1):

To retrieve the no. from from document, use the below link

[Getting char from string at specified index in the visual basic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17127272/getting-char-from-string-at-specified-index-in-the-visual-basic)

and for saving the file

```
Sub ExampleToSaveWorkbook()
Workbooks.Add
'Saving the Workbook
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs "C:\WorkbookName.xls"
'OR
'ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="C:\WorkbookName1.xls"
End Sub
```

Comment: The example shown is specific to Excel and not Word.  Yes, the command is similar but a less-experienced asker could be confused.